# Rails ignoring validations when persisting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an issue where my `City` model is creating several duplicates and somehow ignoring my validations.

My controller is instantiating a `Family` record and assigning a city as follows:

```
f = Family.new 
f.assign_city('Seattle', 'Washington') # put in literals as examples
```

Then, in my Family model, I have the `assign_city` method:

```
def assign_city(city_name, state_name)
  raise(GeoException, 'Both city and state names must be present') 
  unless city_name.present? && state_name.present?
  existing_city = City.query_by_name_and_state(city_name, 
    state_name).first
  if existing_city
    self.city = existing_city
  else
    self.city = City.create! name: city_name, state: state_name, 
      country: 'USA', description: ''
  end
end
```

My `City` model has the following entry:

```
validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: {scope: :state}
validates :state, presence: true, numericality: false

scope :query_by_name_and_state, (->(city, state) {
  if city.present? && state.present?
    where('LOWER(name) LIKE ? AND LOWER(state) LIKE ?', city.downcase, 
     state.downcase)
  else
    where '' # to prevent exception to be raised if city, state are nil
  end
})
```

I'm perplexed for two reasons:

1. The program should not have even entered the ELSE flow to create a new city, because there was already a city with the same name and state.
2. After entering the ELSE flow, it should not have succeeded in creating a record, as this is NOT allowed from the validations, as you can see.

That said, I somehow have 17 duplicate cities with the same name and state!

PS- If it also helps, I did a `City.where('Seattle', 'Washington').map(&:is_valid?)` and get an array of `[false, false, false,...]`

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: if you're using inline `unless` you need to put it on the same line. I don't even know how this managed to compile because it's missing a `end` for that `unless` line

Comment: You should have a uniqueness constraint in your database to protect you from race conditions and bugs in your code. Then you'd want to have a class method in `City` to find or create a city and this class method would need to be able to handle uniqueness constraint violation exceptions from your database. Model validations are not enough. Broken code is temporary, broken data is often forever.

Comment: Could that be because of [transaction isolation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/transaction-iso.html)? I would try to make use of [explicit db locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/explicit-locking.html)

Comment: I tested your code and am unable to reproduce the behavior you're getting.  What version of Rails are you running?  also can you post method definition of `City.query_by_name_and_state`  I assume it's just `City.where(name: city_name, state: state_name` but that's the only thing I can't test.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do this conditional logic, you can use `find_or_create_by`

```
def assign_city(city_name, state_name)
  raise(GeoException, 'Both city and state names must be present') unless city_name.present? && state_name.present?

  self.city = City.find_or_create_by name: city_name, state: state_name, country: 'USA', description: ''
end
```

It's hard to know why you're not getting model validation errors. I suspect it's because you're operating on an unpersisted instance of `Family`. But if you wanted to be safe, you would do `city.valid?` in your conditional logic.  But the best practice is to include db level validation if you want to insure data integrity as there are ways to bypass / override model validations in rails.  Your migration might look like this:

```
class ChangeCity < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
     add_index :cities, [:city_name, :state_name],  unique: true
  end
end
```

Having this will raise db level errors which don't rely on model validation.  You'll also need to remove dupes first or this migration will fail.

UPDATE:  I tested your City scope method and found it may not be very reliable as you can see here if we pass empty strings for city and stage look what happens:

```
simple_soundcloud_app(main)> existing_city = City.query_by_name_and_state('', '').first
  City Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "cities".* FROM "cities" ORDER BY "cities"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<City:0x007f84790c2308
 id: 1,
 name: "New York",
 state: "NY",
 created_at: Sun, 01 Apr 2018 22:58:35 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Sun, 01 Apr 2018 22:58:35 UTC +00:00>
```

This doesn't answer the question as to why your validation didn't fire as expected  However we can't be sure of the input data you used or how the duplicates got created in the first place.  I would recommend writing unit tests for all your methods and test all edge cases.

UPDATE 2, let's fix your scope method as there are so many things wrong with it, especially the hack as illustrated above. Your scope expects arguments so don't call it without the as that is anti-pattern.  You should probably be using a gem like https://github.com/loureirorg/city-state or something. But if you're going to manage the data, normalize it to downcase everything. Then this will work:

```
class City < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :families
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: {scope: :state}
  validates :state, presence: true, numericality: false

  scope :query_by_name_and_state, -> (city, state) {
      where(name: city.downcase, state: state.downcase)
  }

  before_save :normalize_data

  def normalize_data
    self.name.downcase!
    self.state.downcase!
  end
end


simple_soundcloud_app(main)> existing_city = City.query_by_name_and_state('Boston', 'MA').first
  City Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "cities".* FROM "cities" WHERE "cities"."name" = ? AND "cities"."state" = ? ORDER BY "cities"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["name", "boston"], ["state", "ma"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<City:0x007fce6a34e5c8
 id: 3,
 name: "boston",
 state: "ma",
 created_at: Sun, 08 Apr 2018 01:29:43 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Sun, 08 Apr 2018 01:29:43 UTC +00:00>
 simple_soundcloud_app(main)> existing_city = City.query_by_name_and_state('', '').first
  City Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "cities".* FROM "cities" WHERE "cities"."name" = ? AND "cities"."state" = ? ORDER BY "cities"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["name", ""], ["state", ""], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> nil
```

Comment: But [`find_or_create_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by) on its own isn't enough.You still need a unique constraint in the database and some exception handling wrapped around the `find_or_create_by` call. And don't you want a `:unique` on that `add_index`?

Comment: Thanks. But what I find perplexing is that the conditional check didn't find an existing record right before saving, when in fact there were up to six records with the same city and state name.

Comment: It's hard for me to help without knowing how `query_by_name_and_state` is defined.  Please post that code. Also, what ruby version and what rails version?

Comment: @lacostenycoder thanks. Ruby 2.3, Rails 5.1.4, and I just posted the scope method

Comment: can we be sure the duplicate records were created by your controller method?  Also your query is unreliable. See my updated answer.